# Issue with launching Feedback Hub from UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I followed these two docs ([Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/launch-feedback-hub-from-your-app), [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/microsoft-store-services-sdk#install-the-sdk)) to integrate Feedback hub in my app. I used NuGet to install the Microsoft Store Services SDK.

As recommended I am using `StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher.IsSupported()` to check if the Feedback hub is available or not. This works locally on my machine, but in production all customers hit `System.Exception` with message `"Method 'StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher.IsSupported()' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in HomePage.<feedback_tapped>d__23.MoveNext(). There may have been a missing assembly."`

I have read the docs again and don't seem to have missed any of mentioned the steps.

### Edit

This app is a Desktop Bridge app. The solution has a UWP app which communicates with a win32 exe. I am trying to launch the app from UWP app. The solution has a Windows Application Packaging project to package the app.

Comment: "Feedback Hub is available only on devices that run version 10.0.14271 or later" Maybe your users are running an older version of Windows?

Comment: To determine exactly that, this API is provided, StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher.IsSupported()

Comment: Can you check if your project has a framework dependency on the Store FX Package? Open the AppX Manifest file "as code" and look at the dependencies.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT, I hope you meant the "Package.appxmanifest" file, I didn't find anything related to "Store FX" in it. Also, I have updated the question to provide one more info, the app is a Desktop Bridge app, there is UWP app which communicates with win32 exe. I am trying to launch the Feedback hub from the UWP app. There are two Package.appxmanifest files, one in the UWP app and another one in 'Windows Application Packaging Project'.

Comment: Actually it won't show in the `package.appxmanifest` file - you need to look in the real AppXManifest file that is generated when you build / package your application. It should have a line like this: `<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement" MinVersion="10.0.17112.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />` inside the `<Dependencies>` element.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT, yes the AppXManifest has dependency for Store
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement" MinVersion="10.0.17112.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />